# RAW Data from embedded resource image

Tags: vb.net, image, embedded-resource

I am trying to retrieve an image from an Embedded resource, and displaying it in its RAW DATA format (i.e. -> junk text data).

Basically, I am running into a wall with everything I attempt.
Can someone show me how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following [msdn ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx)

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName)
```

That will give you a Stream which you can then use [code cite](http://snipplr.com/view/2012/stream-to-byte-array/) to convert to a byte array which is pretty much the raw data.

```
private Function GetStreamAsByteArray(ByVal stream As System.IO.Stream) As Byte()
Dim streamLength As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length)
Dim fileData As Byte() = New Byte(streamLength) {}
' Read the file into a byte array
stream.Read(fileData, 0, streamLength)
stream.Close()
Return fileData
End Function
```